# Magento 1.9.x - How to speed up adding to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, pagespeed

I am trying to **speed up** my **add-to-cart buttons**. Right now, it takes about 5 seconds from when you press the button until it goes into the cart. Seems a little excessive to me...
This is being tested by the add-to-cart button on the catalog page (not product page) and using the mini cart.

Using the network tab of the inspector on Chrome, I can see it's taking 4.8 seconds to load this:

http://storeapp.themightycompany.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3N0b3JlYXBwLnRoZW1pZ2h0eWNvbXBhbnkuY29tL2NhdGFsb2cvY2F0ZWdvcnkvdmlldy9pZC82/product/71/form_key/pGlDf5Xj0JU5dEwT/

I don't really know what that is, or if that is a clue to how I can speed this up?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That form_key check is for security purposes.  Can you try these: https://www.goivvy.com/blog/5-fixes-slow-magento-19-checkout-add-to-cart